# How to set the width of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have a JTable in a JScrollPane. I want the minimum width to be around 600 as its a wide table. I tried setting the minimum size on the table, the scroll pane, and the panel its self. The size doesn't change at all, what am I missing? Its hard to google this because all that comes up is how to set the width of the columns.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
class SearchResults extends JPanel {

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public SearchResults() {
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    String[][] data= new String[][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "VIEW BUTTON"},
            {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "VIEW BUTTON"}};
    String[] col = new String[] {
            "Last Name", "First Name", "Middle Initial", "Phone Number", "Email", "Project Title", "Project Description", "Amount", "Date Approved", "Date Completed", "College", "Faculty Mentor Name", "Co Grantee", "Major", "Travel Required", "Travel Purpose", "Travel Cost", "Travel Start Date", "Travel End Date", "View"};

      JTable table = new JTable(data,col);
      table.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,200));
      JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
      JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
      pane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 23));
      table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
      add(pane);
}

}
```

And here is where I add it to the JFrame:

```
public class Test extends JFrame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.run();
    }

    public Test()
    {
        super("JAVA TEST!");
    }

    private void run()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SearchResults resultsPanel = new SearchResults();
        resultsPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600,200));
        add(resultsPanel);
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several problems:

- (as already mentioned in my comment) the FlowLayout of the inner panel always sizes its children to their respective prefSize
- a table's min/pref/max width is calculated from the sum of the respective column sizes
- a table is-a Scrollable and as such publishes its preferredScrollableViewportSize (which is the size a surrounding JScrollPane uses to calculates its own prefSize)
- the implementation of prefScrollable is ... lacking (to put it mildly) in that its hard-coded to something like 400 x 450 (or similar)

Consequestly, there are several screws to tweak (after removing all setXXSize calls :) )

- make the panel use a BorderLayout: the scrollPane will fill the complete area if the frame is resized.
- extend the JTable to return something reasonable for prefScrollableViewportSize (f.i. in terms of the pref number of visible columns/rows)

In code (and using JXTable of the SwingX project because it already has api for the second :-) )

```
String[][] data= new String[][] {
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "VIEW BUTTON"},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "VIEW BUTTON"}};
String[] col = new String[] {
        "Last Name", "First Name", "Middle Initial", "Phone Number", 
        "Email", "Project Title", "Project Description", "Amount", 
        "Date Approved", "Date Completed", "College", "Faculty Mentor Name", 
        "Co Grantee", "Major", "Travel Required", "Travel Purpose", 
        "Travel Cost", "Travel Start Date", "Travel End Date", "View"};

 JXTable table = new JXTable(data,col);
 table.setVisibleColumnCount(10);
 table.setHorizontalScrollEnabled(true);
 JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
 JComponent comp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 comp.add(pane);
```

**Edit**

To solve the 80% requirement (and a little teaser for MigLayout :-) )

```
// 80% with a minimum of 600 logical pixel:
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap 2, debug",
        "[600:pref, fill, grow][20%]");
JComponent comp = new JPanel(layout);
comp.add(pane, "spany");
comp.add(new JLabel("just something"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I put it in a border layout and it seems to look good. You are missing a right parenthesis on the line above where the code starts. Its driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 0):

had some Problems with this stuff too. use the `setPreferedSize(new Dimension(800,600));` too.
this could solve your problem

Comment: That worked! I set the preferred size on the JScrollPane, setting it on the others didn't seem to have an effect. Also you spelled preferred wrong. Thanks!

Comment: no - never ever call any of the setXXSize of components: [some reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519)

Comment: @kleopatra How would you suggest I fix the width problem?

Comment: @Steve - even if it seems to be helping now, it's asking for pain in future. Simply don't, never.

Comment: @kleopatra I'm not suggesting you're wrong. I'm asking what is the correct way to achieve what I'm attempting.

Comment: simultaneous comments :-) @Steve the answer to layout problems is always the same: choose a suitable LayoutManager. Here the problem stems from the FlowLayout of the inner panel which will size everything to its pref

Comment: with the Gridbaglayout for example, if you initialize an empty JTextfield it will be shown as an JTextfield with a width around 25. This is a pretty solid way to initialize Components with a fixed with or height. Sorry for the misspelling ;)

Comment: @kelopatra which layout manager should I be using? I could live with like 80% width of the page, but I have a feeling thats not something that can be easily obtained with java from my limited experience

Comment: @Steve If you are allowed to go for a third party manager: my current favourite is MigLayout. It's highly flexible, powerful (nearly nothing it can't do and intuitive to use. What do you mean by _80% width of the page_ ?

Comment: @kleopatra sorry I'm a web developer haha. 80% the width of the window, so if its maximized it should still be 80%

Answer (score 0):

Layout matters. IDE like [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) provides hands free layout design by drag and drop.

You can achieve even by code once you understand [Swing layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Few most used layouts I'm mentioning here

```
BorderLayout
BoxLayout
FlowLayout
GridLayout
```

in yours, if you add `panel.setLayout( new GridLayout(1,1));`, table will get fixed within frame.

Also you need not extend `JPanel` or `JFrame` unless if you overwrite something or adding more stuff to frame. Practice to learn.